# Trying to get bytes and append using NSMutableData for a video through Asset Library gives memory full error

Tags: cocoa, assets

I’m trying to upload a video of size 100MB through Asset Library. But when i try to use `-(NSUInteger)getBytes:(uint8_t *)buffer fromOffset:(long long)offset length:(NSUInteger)length error:(NSError **)error` of `ALAssetRepresentation` I get memory full error. I also need to put the data in buffer to `NSData`. How can i achieve that?

Comment: You know that the iPhone 3G has 128MB ram total? You don't say how much of the 100MB video you are trying to load into your buffer at one time. Hopefully not the entire thing.

Comment: Hi Guys,

I am looking for the same, did you guys have any luck???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried this way:

```
Byte *buffer = (Byte*)malloc(asset.defaultRepresentation.size);

NSUInteger k = [asset.defaultRepresentation getBytes:buffer fromOffset: 0.0
                length:asset.defaultRepresentation.size error:nil];

NSData *adata = NSData *adata = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer
                                 length:j freeWhenDone:YES];
```

It really works!

Comment: This will not work for large files as in the question. Your suggestion will try to allocate 100 MB of ram in that case. The trick is to do it iteratively and use the offset to read and write chunks of data.

Answer (score 0):

As @runeb said the answer is not working properly with large files. You should do something like that:

```
            int bufferSize = 2048;
            int offset = 0;

            NSString* name=nil;
            while(offset<asset.size){
                Byte *buffer = (Byte*)malloc(bufferSize);
                NSUInteger buffered = [asset getBytes:buffer fromOffset:offset length:bufferSize error:nil];
                NSData *data;

                data = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:buffered freeWhenDone:NO];

                if(!name){
                    //Creates the file and gives it a unique name
                    name = [FileUtils saveVideoFromAsset:data];
                }
                else{
                    //Append data to the file created...
                    [FileUtils appendData:data toFile:name];
                }
                offset+=buffered;
               free(buffer);
            }
```

In order to append data to a file you can use that:

```
NSFileHandle *myHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:filePath];
    [myHandle seekToEndOfFile];
    [myHandle writeData:videoData];
```

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

ust add @autoreleasepool block, so that any autorleased objects should be cleaned up. it looks like that ARC has something changed after iOS7

```
@autoreleasepool {
     NSUInteger readStatus = [rep getBytes:buffer fromOffset:_startFromByte length:chunkSize error:NULL];
}
```